# How can I get Node tokens to be available for my fields

Tags: nodes, entities, tokens

I am currently using Background Field module to set a background image and I want to set the css selector to incorporate node->nid. However it seems to not be available for me to use in my field but under the list of tokens available throughout my site I can see it there. I haven't been able to pinpoint how to do this. I've attached screenshots to help.

I am using Drupal 7.34 and Token 7.x-1.5.

[image: Node not available]
[image: All available tokens]